# Bind event to wx.button directy using wx.EVT_BUTTON?

Tags: python, wxpython

I read several wxPython books and am now quite familiar with binding a button with an event. Such as in a wx.Frame's __init__ method, I wrote:

```
self.btn = wx.Button(self, 2, "click me")
self.btn.bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onclick)
```

where `onclick` is something need to do when the button is clicked.

Recently, I am reading someone's wxPython code and come across the following code:

```
wx.Button(self, 2, "click me")
wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 2, self.onclick)
```

The writer use the above way to bind method for every button. Thus I have two questions:

1. The wx.Button is instantiated by not bound to any variable. Does that means it will be garbage-collected?
2. I cannot find any document about calling wx.EVT_BUTTON directly. What actually it creates? What is the difference between it and using the `bind()` function?

Comment: That's a very old syntax.  Some years ago it was the only way to do it, and I guess it still works.  But now it's recommended to use the new syntax, which is the one you show in your first example.

Comment: Let's not forget `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.btn, self.onclick)` https://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

Answer (score 1):

Paul's comment is correct, but here is some more information:

To answer #1, no it will not be garbage collected. The parent window owns the C++ part of the button object, which in turn has a reference to the Python part of the button object. So the Python object will continue to exist as long as the C++ object does.

For #2: There is very little difference. Many years ago the `wx.EVT_*` items in wx used to be ordinary functions.  Now they are instances of the `wx.PyEventBinder` class which have a `__call__` method to provide compatibility with the old functions. But as Paul mentioned, using the binder instances with the `Bind` method from the `wx.Window` class is preferred as it's more pythonic and makes the code a bit more self-explanitory.